# prob with laravel input not found

Tags: laravel

I am trying to take a variable from a textbox called 'skill' and dump whatever is typed but I get:

HandymanController.php line 32:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

How come? It's a built-in feature isn't it?

```
$searchTerm = Input::get('skill');
    var_dump($searchTerm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2, the Input alias was removed. You can still use it by adding it to your `config/app.php` file, but rather than doing that, the simplest way is probably to use the [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request) helper function:

```
$searchTerm = request('skill');
```

You can also use the `Request` facade:

```
use Request;

$searchTerm = Request::input('skill');
```

You can even use method injection:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function someControllerMethod(Request $request)
{
    $searchTerm = $request->skill;
}
```

But in my opinion, the simplest way is the helper function (the first suggested method) since you don't need to "import" anything.

Answer (score 1):

run this：

`composer dump-autoload`

and check the namespace, because Laravel 5 promotes the use of namespaces for things like Class, Models and Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Input;` to the top of your class **or** use it like this:

```
$searchTerm = \Input::get('skill');
```

Alternatively, you could use [$request->input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input):

```
$searchTerm = $request->input('skill');
```

Comment: I did use Input; and now I get Fatal error: Class 'Input' not found

Comment: Look carefully, you should add \ before `Input`.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try `$request->input('skill');`? If yes, what error does it creates? Or it's working?